# How to make checkbox unchecked on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, scripting

I am using a jqgrid. T want to add a checkbox to header so that on selecting that header checkbox all the checkboxes in every row has to be selected. How to add that header checkbox?

Also I have added checkbox to each row using the following code.

```
{
    name: 'checkbox',
    index: 'checkbox',
    editable:true,
    checked:false,
    edittype:'checkbox',
    align:"center",
    hidden : adminHide,
    editoptions: { value:"True:False"},
    formatter: "checkbox",
    formatoptions: {disabled : false,checked:false}
}
```

Problem with this is, by default checkbox are checked. I want the checkboxes to be unchecked on load. What is the change I need to make in my code?

Comment: Can someone pls help me on this? It is very urgent..:(

Answer (score 0):

`hidden : adminHide,`
what this means. Is it a variable??
I guess hidden property has either true or false values.
After commenting the above . it works.